# Running Tensorflow in Anaconda3

Tags: tensorflow, import, anaconda

I am trying to run Tensorflow in Anaconda Navigator. I installed Tensorflow to a new environment which I called tf. Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import layers

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense
```

The error message is `unable to import tensorflow` and `No module named tensorflow`

Comment: What does `conda list` output?

Comment: Here is a partial list:
tensorboard               2.3.0              pyh4dce500_0
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.6.0                      py_0
tensorflow                2.3.0           mkl_py38h8c0d9a2_0
tensorflow-base           2.3.0           eigen_py38h75a453f_0
tensorflow-datasets       1.2.0                    py38_0
tensorflow-estimator      2.3.0              pyheb71bc4_0
tensorflow-metadata       0.14.0             p

Comment: You should have something like this`tensorboard 2.0.1 pypi_0 pypi`.

Comment: I don't see anything like that in there.

Comment: Then try `conda install tensorflow`.

Comment: I got a lot of conflicts. For example, Package pbr conflicts for:
mock -> pbr
pytables -> mock -> pbr

Comment: It's just warnings does it work now?

Comment: No, I get the same module not found error. Could it be that it is not finding the path to the tf environment?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to install on Anaconda environment.

```
#Set Up Anaconda Environments
conda create --name tf_env python=3.7
#Activate the new Environment
source activate tf_env
#Install tensorflow
tf_env$pip install tensorflow 
#Verify installation
tf_env$python
>import tensorflow as tf
>tf.__version__
```